# How Can I demonstrate this grammar is not ambiguous?

Tags: regex, compiler-construction, grammar

I know I need to show that there is no string that I can get using only left most operation that will lead to two different parsing trees. But how can I do it? I know there is not a simple way of doing it, but since this exercise is on the compilers Dragon book, then I am pretty sure there is a way of showing (no need to be a formal proof, just justfy why) it.
The Gramar is:

> S-> SS* | SS+ | a

What this grammar represents is another way of simple arithmetic(I do not remember the name if this technique of anyone knows, please tell me ) : normal sum arithmetic has the form a+a, and this just represents another way of summing and multiplying. So aa+ also mean a+a, aaa*+ is a*a+a and so on

Comment: You can produce the string 'aa' two ways: S -> SS* -> S(S) -> aa; and S -> SS+ -> S(S) -> aa.

Comment: Im sorry, I need to show that it is not ambiguous. I know it is actually not because I have the answer, but it does not show how to demonstrate. The example you use does not work, because for what I got of it, you used left most operation and then right most operation, you need to be able to produce it in two different ways using only left most operations, and then generate two diffent trees.

Comment: So what is it? Your question title says that you want to demonstrate that the grammar **is** ambiguous, but your comment says that you want to show that it **is not** ambiguous. (If the latter is what you intend, please edit your question and correct the title.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The easiest way to prove that a CFG is unambiguous is to construct an unambiguous parser. If the grammar is LR(k) or LL(k) and you know the value of *k*, then that is straightforward.

This particular grammar is LR(0), so the parser construction is almost trivial; you should be able to do it on a single sheet of paper (which is worth doing before you try to look up the answer.

The intuition is simple: every production ends with a different terminal symbol, and those terminal symbols appear nowhere else in the grammar. So when you read a symbol, you know precisely which production to use to reduce; there is only one which can apply, and there is no left-hand side you can shift into.

If you invert the grammar to produce Polish (or Łukasiewicz) notation, then you get a trivial LL grammar. Again the parsing algorithm is obvious, since every right hand side starts with a unique terminal, so there is only one prediction which can be made:

```
S → * S S | + S S | a
```

So that's also unambiguous. But the infix grammar is ambiguous:

```
S → S * S | S + S | a
```

The easiest way to provide ambiguity is to find a sentence which has two parses; one such sentence in this case is:

```
a + a + a
```

Answer (score -1):

I think the example string `aa` actually shows what you need. Can it not be parsed as:

`S => SS* => aa` OR `S => SS+ => aa`

Comment: You are forgetting the * and the +, they are not regex simbols(* repeat zero or more times) and (+ repeat 1 one more times). Those simbols actually need to be in the derivations

Comment: The kleene star and kleene plus are actually exactly like their regex implementations. Maybe your syntax is different from the standard? Sorry if this didn't help.

Comment: No worries, it is totally fine. Just to explain better, some possible strings that can be generated using this grammar:
SS*,SS+,SSS+*,SS+S*,SS*S+ and so son..

Comment: You should update your question to reflect that. However, I suspect you're misinterpreting the grammar. The `S`, `+`, and `*` symbols are almost certainly not intended to be literal. The strings that this grammar can generate (using standard syntax) is `a^n` for `n>1` That is to say, `{a,aa,aaa,aaa,aaaa. . .}`

Comment: I was in my teacher class today, I am pretty sure it is not, but you can check right here: https://www.dropbox.com/s/a4ibf77x2o2g3lt/Capture.PNG?dl=0

Comment: I'd get some clarification from your professor on that one. Looks like he's being ambiguous with those plusses and stars.

Comment: He told me what this grammar represents, I do not remember at the moment, but I remember an example: normal sum arithmetic has the form a+a, and this just represents another way of summing and multiplying. So aa+ also mean a+a, aaa*+ is a*a+a and so on, I am sure this Technic has its own name of representation.

Comment: That clarified a lot. I'll probably post here again tomorrow. I recommend updating your question with this info as its kind of strange

Comment: It's called "Reverse Polish Notation". [Read all about it.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Reverse_Polish_notation). It's named after the late Polish mathematician Jan Łukasiewicz, whose nationality is easier on anglo tongues than his surname.